# Ввод в консоли

Tags: objective-c

Есть такой код:

```
char tmpBuff[255];
fgets(tmpBuff, 255, stdin);

NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:tmpBuff length:255
    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Но проблема в том, что в строку копируется так же и мусор. Я ввожу "Hello World!".
Пробовал обрабатывать с помощью `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` но не помогло.
Подскажите как правильно считать ввод из консоли в строку.

Comment: У меня ваш код прекрасно работает кстати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 char* ch = new char [255];
 gets(ch);
 l = strlen(ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой оператор как `scanf():`

```
char tmpBuff[255];  
// выражение в квадратных скобках указывает на то,   
// что нужно считывать всю строку с пробелами  
scanf("%[^\n]s",tmpBuff);

NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: tmpBuff     
                                            length: sizeof(tmpBuff)   
                                          encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];  
NSLog(@"%@",tmpStr);
```

UPD.

```
int newLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (tmpBuff[i] != ' ') { newLength++;}
   else  break;
```

Comment: но проблему это не решило, [tmpStr length] по прежнему равен 255. А мне надо знать реальный размер строки, т.е. до \n

Comment: Так вы и не спрашивали об этом вроде как. См. UPD.

Comment: Согласен, не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос, я делал трим, но он не работал, все действительно намного проще оказалось.